# print header from the matching columns' entries

Tags: python

I want to print the column headers, where entries from the data-column match with the rest of the columns entries.

I have a text file (test1.txt) in the following format:

```
data      a1    a2    a3    a4
a         bb    aa    cc    dd
a         bb    cc    aa    dd
b         bb    cc    cc    dd
b         bb    bb    cc    bb
```

Expected output:

```
a2, a3, a1, a1, a2, a4
```

What I am doing:

```
with open("test1.txt",'rU') as ij:
    i = ij.readlines()
    for j in i:
         j = j.rstrip().split('\t')
         for r in j[1:]:
              if r.startswith(str(j[0])):
                   print(r)
```

What I am getting:

```
aa
aa
bb
bb
bb
bb
```

Any tips? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because you are printing `r` which is the value of that matches current `data` value instead of the column header.

To get the column header, read the first line, and keep it as a list. Then print the header value when a match is found

```
with open("test1.txt",'rU') as ij:
    firstLine = ij.readline()
    headers = firstLine.rstrip().split('\t')[1:] # get headers

    i = ij.readlines() # read the rest of the data
    for j in i:
         j = j.rstrip().split('\t')
         for r in range(len(j[1:])): # loop based on index
              if j[1+r].startswith(str(j[0])): # use j[1+r]
                   print(headers[r]) # print headers instead
```

Comment: looks promising, what is the reason of using j[1+r] ?

Comment: so that it won't checks whether j[0] starts with j[0], it will start by cheking whether j[1] starts with j[0], j[2] starts with j[0], and so on